# Need addRange google sheet function to read backwards

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, charts, google-visualization

I have the following code, and it works and brings me a nice chart but i want google sheet **addRange** function to read ranges backwards, let's say from **B13 to B1** for example. Any idea how can i acomplish that?

```
    function newChart() {
    
          removeChartsOne("mysheet");
          const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
          const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("mysheet");
         
          var headerRow = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,5).getValues()
          chart = sheet.newChart()
            .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.LINE)  
            .addRange(sheet.getRange('B1:B13'))    
            .addRange(sheet.getRange('C1:C13'))    
            .addRange(sheet.getRange('D1:D13'))  
            .addRange(sheet.getRange('E1:E13'))  
            .setOption('title','Title')  
            .setOption('pointShape','circle')
            .setOption('pointSize','7')
            .setPosition(5, 5, 0, 0)  
            .setOption('series', 
             {0:{labelInLegend:headerRow[0][2]},
              1:{labelInLegend:headerRow[0][3]},
              2:{labelInLegend:headerRow[0][4]}
            })
            .build();
        
          sheet.insertChart(chart);
          
        }
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot imagine your expected result from `addRange function to read ranges backwards, let's say from B13 to B1 for example.`. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: For example, do you want to turn on "Reverse axis order" in "Horizontal axis"?

Comment: Can you also share a minimum reproducble sample, so we can have an idea how your data works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`hAxis.direction`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/chart-configuration-options#line-chart-configuration-options) controls the direction in which the values along the horizontal axis grow. You can set it to '-1' to reverse the order of the values.

Here's the modified part of your script:

```js
function newChart() {
    // ... existing code ...

    chart = sheet.newChart()
      // ... existing chart setup ...
      .setOption('hAxis', { direction: -1 })  // Set horizontal axis direction
      .build();

    sheet.insertChart(chart);
}
```

Comment: That worked and solves the question, im going to check as solved, but i wanted to ask you if you know a way to read the values horizontal (from A1, to B1,  C1, etc etc) instead of vertical  (A1:A15)

Comment: @AlonsodelVillar I'm not entirely sure if I've understood your requirement correctly, It sounds like you want to switch rows and columns in your chart. You can use [.setTransposeRowsAndColumns(true)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-column-chart-builder#settransposerowsandcolumnstranspose) in your chart configuration for this. It will transpose the data, reading it horizontally instead of vertically.